# Make hovering over a parent element only affect its own text, not child elements

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Trying to do a very simple effect. I want only the brackets to become red when you hover over the `h1`. The `span` should stay black.

My HTML:

```
<h1>{ <span>js</span> }</h1>
```

My CSS:

```
h1 span:hover {
 /* make the color of just the brackets red here */
}
```

And here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9g1nmt9x/2/

I've read a few other SO questions that were similar to this one, but a lot of them seem to use jQuery. Is there any way to simply do this with just CSS without delving into JS? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make the `h1` change color on hover, while keeping the `span` inside the `h1` black.

```css
h1:hover {
  color: red;
}

h1:hover span {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<h1>{ <span>js</span> }</h1>
```

Comment: Well I feel silly now, that was a pretty obvious work-around. Thanks!

And @EdCottrell thanks for that note but for my purposes this should be fine.